# How to give all service accounts in namespace the same cluster role?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a group of service accounts in namespace `prometheus` and I have a cluster role for reading all pods in my cluster. How can I build `ClusterRoleBinding` to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to [K8s docs about Using RBAC Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)

And scroll down to examples, you can see this one:

> For all service accounts in the "qa" namespace:
>
> ```
> subjects:
> - kind: Group
>   name: system:serviceaccounts:qa
>   apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
> ```

---

You can now take it and apply to your usecase:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: <some-fancy-name>
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: <clusterrolename>
subjects:
- kind: Group
  name: system:serviceaccounts:prometheus
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

---

There is also one different example worth to notice:

> 3. Grant a role to all service accounts in a namespace
>
> If you want all applications in a namespace to have a role, no matter
> what service account they use, you can grant a role to the service
> account group for that namespace.
>
> For example, grant read-only permission within "my-namespace" to all
> service accounts in that namespace:
>
> ```
> kubectl create rolebinding serviceaccounts-view \
>   --clusterrole=view \
>   --group=system:serviceaccounts:my-namespace \
>   --namespace=my-namespace
> ```